# How to pass form input values to another page in Wordpress with Elementor

Tags: wordpress, forms, custom-wordpress-pages, elementor

I have searched the web for answer for almost a day and I couldn't find any answer about that.

Assuming that I'm having a Form created by the simple elementor form widget, and a client inserting a data there(name, email, number) and in another page I have some icon buttons(email, whatsapp, etc..) that should redirect the client to contact me
Like this one:

```
https://wa.me/1XXXXXXXXXX (Whatsapp start a chat link)
```

What I want to accomplish is that the input value from "Phone field" will replace the "1XXXXXXX" in the URL after the form is submitted

Is there any way to accomplish that? or any guide?

Answer (score 0):

You can use POST method of php.
All you have to do is to create a page (i.e. `submit`) and then create a file in your theme folder (rather use child theme) with the name `page-submit.php` and write down your php code in it (use cpanel/direct admin to edit the file). Also, you should send your form to submit page, use action attribute in your form tag.